# Continue the squence of hexagons

Tags: logical-deduction, geometry, sequence

This is from [c't, a German IT magazine](https://ftp.heise.de/ct/listings/2023/21/dreierkombo.pdf) (link will download file). You see seven hexagons, each with seven green and blue dots, following a specific rule. Find out what colors the circles must have to continue the sequence.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! What is the source of this puzzle?

Comment: ct-Magazin, a german IT magazine, https://ftp.heise.de/ct/listings/2023/21/dreierkombo.pdf

Answer (score 6):

The answer is

> 2, 4, 5, 6,

because

> a little squeezing will create a seven segment display with the letters `a` to `g`. Since the sequence had to be continued the last segment inevitably represents an `h`.

> [image]